# Using for loop inside declaration of variable

Tags: c++

Can I use for loop inside declaration a variable?

```
int main() {
    int a = {
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            b += i;
        }
        return b;
    };

    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Comment: Use a function/lambda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a lambda:

```
int main() {
    int a = []{
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            b += i;
        }
        return b;
    }();

    printf("%d", a);
}
```

It's important to note that you have to immediately execute it otherwise you attempt to store the lambda. Therefore the extra `()` at the end.

If you intent to reuse the lambda for multiple instantiations, you can store it separately like this:

```
int main() {
    auto doCalculation = []{
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            b += i;
        }
        return b;
    };

    int a = doCalculation();

    printf("%d", a);
}
```

If you need it in more than one scope, use a function instead.

Comment: Thanks! What about I want to have another declaration of variable above `a` (`unsigned char x = 7`) and I want to `return x*b`. It gets me `error: void value not ignored as it ought to be` and `error: ‘x’ is not captured`.

Comment: You need to capture it e.g. `[x]{` but it's hard to say without code. Please read some more about lambdas and captures, e.g. here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda or simply google the term, then you will find many tutorials

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just didn't know the term.

Comment: We are not talking about **declaration** here, even not **definition**. We are talking about **initialization**, and especially about **copy initialization**. Please see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization . But tons of upvotes and an accepted answer, so everything perfectly OK. +1 from my end.  If we would be strict: The only correct answer to the given question is simply: "No, not possible"

Answer (score 0):

actually has been prepared by C++ committee..
`constexpr` has many usefulness not yet exlpored

```
constexpr int b(int l) {
            int b=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
                b += i;
            return b;
        }

int main() {

    constexpr int a = b(5);

    printf("%d", a);
}
```